# Javascript error on setAttribute function

Tags: javascript, html

Im getting this error. Code seems fine, then im using jsfiddle, but in my page not working getting error:

> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null.`

```js
let max = 2160;
let progress = 80;
document.querySelector(".fill").setAttribute(
  "style",
  "stroke-dashoffset: " + ((100 - progress) / 100) * max);
```

```html
<div class="user-avatar-holder">
  <div class="skill-bar">
    <svg class="skill blue noselect" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 776 628">
                                <path class="track" d="M723 314L543 625.77 183 625.77 3 314 183 2.23 543 2.23 723 314z"></path>
                                <path class="fill" d="M723 314L543 625.77 183 625.77 3 314 183 2.23 543 2.23 723 314z"></path>
                            </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="profile-image-outer">
    <div class="profile-image">
      <img src="/img/default/no_user-150.png" alt="" width="100" height="100">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: So it's telling you that `document.querySelector(".fill")` is `null`. Have you checked your HTML, is there an element with that class?

Comment: @El_Vanja updated post with HTML

Comment: Where is the script included? Have you ensured that it runs once the page is loaded and not sooner?

Comment: @El_Vanja i'm using laravel. Code included in another blade (Not in main page)

Comment: Alright, but where in that template? At the top? Bottom? You might want to wrap it in an event handler that waits for the page to load to be certain your element will be available.

Comment: @El_Vanja oh u made me on ture road! :) Sorry for bad english. I put code at the end and working! Thanks!

Comment: Use `document.querySelector(".fill").style.strokeDashoffset`

Answer (score -1):

Query selector by class return an Array type, try to add [id] to your html code and then use it

Comment: Not correct. `querySelector` returns the first matching DOM element. `querySelectorAll` on the other hand returns an array of elements.